# Magento checkout page post 404 error

Tags: checkout, upgrade, checkout-page

After upgrading magento to 2.3.4 my checkout page is now broken, giving me an error

`POST mydomain/checkout/ 404 (not found)`
as well as defaultCaptcha.js cannot read property 'timestamp' of undefined'; and misc.js cannot read property of 'status' undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOt sure but try to disable Magent reCaptcha and deploy content

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_PaypalReCaptcha
php bin/magento module:disable MSP_ReCaptcha
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Ref: 
[Bug Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lang' of undefined on product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/285617/bug-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-lang-of-undefined-on-product-page)
https://github.com/magento/magespecialist_ReCaptcha/issues/11

Comment: It was indeed an error with our captcha system, we had multiple captchas enabled